# Conditional taking a variable as non null even though it's null before and after condition

Tags: kotlin

I have this conditional in which I am passing a value that's null so that I can get a certain response in the if part but the thing is, it always goes to the else part, even though the variable is null, as the logs show. I don't understand why it won't work. In fact, if I change my condition to myId != null, I can see inside the if that myId is null so it's as if it's not null before the if, even though it's null. I don't understand. Any help understanding this would be great.

```
myId?.let { Log.v("Notification BEFORE ", it) }
Log.v("Notification ISNULL ", ((myId== null).toString()))
        Log.v("Notification ISEMPTY ", ((myId?.isEmpty()).toString()))
        if (myId == null || myId?.isEmpty() == true) {
            myId?.let { Log.v("Notification INSIDEIF ", it) }
            Toast.makeText(this, "If condition reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            myId?.let { Log.v("NotificationID ELSE ", it) }
            getIntentFromNotification(myId!!)
        }
```

Logs:

```
V/Notification BEFORE: null
V/Notification ISNULL: false
V/Notification ISEMPTY: false
V/NotificationID ELSE: null
```

Logs with myId != null condition:

```
V/Notification BEFORE: null
V/Notification ISNULL: false
V/Notification ISEMPTY: false
V/NotificationID INSIDEIF: null
```

Comment: ``myId?.let { }`` wont run if ``myId`` is null, so the fact that log line is printing at all implies ``myId`` isn't null - and your other checks (not null and not empty) back that up. The parameter passed to the ``let`` is a copy of ``myId`` which can't be modified, so if ``myId`` isn't null, then ``it`` isn't either. If this really is the code you're running, it looks like some weird problem with the ``Log.v`` call. I'd try explicitly logging `it.toString()` or `"$it"`, and maybe use the debugger so you can see exactly what the value is. Any chance `myId` as a string actually is `"null"`?

Comment: @cactustictacs thank you, that explanation actually helps.. I will check if I can retrieve that string to see if it's "null" but, from what you are saying, it might be and I just hadn't thought about it before so thanks!

Comment: @dazai honestly it's the thing that makes most sense to me, and I just thought about it at the end! Personally I'd just stick a breakpoint in there, debug the app, and then when it pauses you can poke around and see if ``myId`` actually is an object, do `Evaluate Expression` to run some code on it and work out what's happening, that kind of thing. Way easier than trying to work it out with log statements

Comment: @cactustictacs  in the end it was a "null" string, like you said, now I won't forget to check for it next time! thank you for the advices!